# react-native-firebase on notification opened with no listeners registered ios

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native-firebase

I'm using onNotificationOpened. On Android it works perfectly, but on ios on clicking on the push in Xcode writes the console "on notification opened with no listener". How can I fix this?
This is my code:

```
  firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
        const registerToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('registerPushToken');
        firebase
        .messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then(async Devicetoken => {
            if (registerToken === Devicetoken) return;
            await dispatch(subscribeNotify(Devicetoken));
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('registerPushToken', Devicetoken);
        });
    });
    firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(async data => {
        const registerToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('registerPushToken');
        if (registerToken) {
            await dispatch(
                unsubscribeNotify({
                    registrationToken: registerToken,
                    deleteInstance: false,
                }),
            );
        }
        await dispatch(subscribeNotify(data));
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('registerPushToken', data);
    });
    firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
        pushController(notificationOpen.notification._data);
    });
```

1. Application Target Platform: iOS 11.3
2. React Native version: 0.55.2
3. RNFirebase Version: 4.0.5
4. Firebase Module: Notifications, Cloud Messaging